# How to make smaller vector from a large one...? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, reshape

I have a large vector with length of 185437, i want to make a new one, reshaped vector with mean values of this one but I need new length to be 180*delay because on x axis i must have like this, for example:

```
   delay=0.1
   x_axis=0:delay:180
```

i need y axis (this new vector) to be same size as this x_axis so I can plot it.
I tried something like:

```
   values_delay_sum_plot=mean(reshape(values_delay_sum,1/delay,length(values_delay_sum)*delay));
```

but it is not working. First errors was for integer values, later that I can't change size of vector. Note that, values_delay_sum is my large vector, a from it I wanna make a new one for my plot. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain better what you want

Comment: Dear, I need to resize my large vector to be able to plot it within these conditions for x axis 0:0.1:180. Not resize it like values_delay_sum(1:1800). I want to have average values of large vector in this smaller one so I do not lose statistical importance of my analysis.

Comment: If you look to your data : `length(Values_delay_sum)*delay` is `185437*0.1 = 18 543.7` and this isn't an integer that can be use for `reshape`. And when you do reshape, size must not change.

Comment: You can try `reshape(values_delay_sum,1800,[])`, the `[]` will compute the size of second dimension. But in your case, the data isn't divisible by 1800, so reshape isn't what you need in your case.

Comment: Maybe an interpolation would be a suitable approach?

Answer (score 0):

As @Schorsch said, i think that you need `interp1` function. Maybe something like this:

```
x_axis=linspace(0,185437,1801);
y_axis=interp1(values_delay_sum,x_axis);
plot(x_axis,y_axis);
```

If you want just to plot the new vector, but not with the corresponds original x_axis values, just plot:

```
plot(y_axis)
```